# Applying an XDT transform to an XML complex type

Tags: xml, azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric application that deploys to multiple environments, each defined by an [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-model-schema-elements#application-element) xml element, which is a complex type. Within this Application element is a list of parameters, and I would like to apply an XDT transform on these parameters.

The target xml looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/SimFabric" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Parameter1" Value="" key="key1"/>
    <Parameter Name="Parameter2" Value="" key="key2"/>
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```

And the Web.*.config I want to paste in takes the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" key="key1" value="value1" />
    <add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" key="key2" value="value2" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Can XDT transform be used to make the values in the second file be placed in the first?

Answer (score 0):

XDT Transforms work for every XML file.
You can test this [here](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/)

**Source:**

```
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        Name="fabric:/SimFabric" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="Parameter1" Value="" />
            <Parameter Name="Parameter2" Value="" />
          </Parameters>
</Application>
```

**XDT Transform:**

```
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/SimFabric"  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
 
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(Name)" Name="Parameter1" Value="Value1" />
    <Parameter xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(Name)" Name="Parameter2" Value="Value2" />
  </Parameters>

</Application>
```

**Result:**

```
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/SimFabric" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Parameter1" Value="Value1" />
    <Parameter Name="Parameter2" Value="Value2" />
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```